# How does Python's exec function work when sending an empty dictionary in the locals parameter?

Tags: python, exec

I have written the following piece of code trying to use exec() to execute the code enclosed in the string. I pass an empty dictionary, d, as the locals parameter. When I print d, the local namespaces are being created in d. Can anyone help me explain that is really happening?

```
c = '''x = 1 
def __init__(self,n):self.name = n 
def printD(self):print(self.name)'''

d = {}
print(d)

exec(c,globals(),d)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If `exec` gets two separate objects as *globals* and *locals*, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

In a class definition, variable assignments update the local environment, not the global environment. So the names you define are put in the dictionary `d`.

If you don't pass the `locals` dictionary the names will be defined in the global environment.